# How to remove programs installed from source using diff?

Tags: diff

Is there a way to remove compiled from source programs rather than make uninstall? Can we take snapshots of filesystem before and after installation and take a diff and remove the installation? Also please tell me how to do it? May i know how can I take snapshot of filesystem before and after installation and take difference? Please I have limited knowledge in this.

Comment: Don't install from source. Period. Use a build server to build custom packages if you need and then install those. Building packages is way too simple to not do this.

Answer (score 2):

- The preferred and professional way to install/remove software is via the system's package manager, if necessary by locally build packages. This takes care of your problems in a sane and manageable way.
- Using file system diffs would require a otherwise quiet system that doesn't create/change files during this whole procedure. This usually is impossible.
- There are tools like `installwatch` that watch the install procedure and logs what happens and use this e.g. to create packages, but they are not available everywhere.